# extract numbers from dates in C

Tags: c, string, char

I got an assignment to convert numbers from a date.

we get the dates as a char string like 18.2.2014 for example, and I need to extract the integers 18, 2, 2014.

my way is not perfect...

what is the best way in your opinion?

```
void luckChoice(char a[]){

    int month=10*(a[3]-'0')+(a[4]-'0');
    int day=(a[0]-'0')*10+(a[1]-'0');
    int year=(a[9]-'0')+(a[8]-'0')*10+(a[7]-'0')*100+(a[6]-'0')*1000;
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use standard library's `atoi()` (ascii to integer) function?

Comment: @SHG  We are not allowed

Comment: how about `sscanf()` function?

Comment: If there are constraints on the functions you are and are not allowed to use for homework, you _must_ state them in the question.  People might suggest things like POSIX [`strptime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strptime.html) — the scanning analogue of standard C [`strftime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strftime.html), which formats date/time values.  It might also be overkill here, and if there are any proscribed functions, it is probably one of them.

Comment: Your code does not validate that you have two digits for the month; it is sad that there's only one digit in the sample date.  It also means your year calculation is off.  That's a good reason for using `strtol()` or `atoi()` or `scanf()` and not your rather naive code.  If you can't use them, write a little function to do the same job.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you are fine with it but you can directly do this in `scanf()` itself.

Just take the input as

```
if (scanf("%d.%d.%d", &dd, &mm, &yy) == 3) { …OK… } else { …failed… }
```

This will ignore the '.' from input in specified sequence.

Else you can use sscanf() function as follows:

```
void luckChoice(char a[]){
     int dd,mm,yy;
     sscanf(a,"%d.%d.%d",&dd,&mm,&yy);
}
```

Comment: I get my input as a string

It is a must

Comment: You can then use sscanf() function as mentioned below in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve this.  A simple question is how much code should be used to detect invalid input?

Staying with the C standard library, code can process the string multiple times and catch many errors.

```
// Expand the f() signature
// void luckChoice(char a[]){
int luckChoice(const char a[], int *year, int *month, int *day) {
```

Check format. `"%n"` saves the offset of the scan *if it got that far*.  `"%*2[0-9]"` matches 1 or 2 digits, yet does not save the result.  This is unlike `"%d"` which allows leadins spaces and `'+'` or `'-'`.

```
  int n = 0;
  sscanf(a, "%*2[0-9].%*2[0-9].%*4[0-9]%n", &n);
```

If `n` is non-zero that the scan was *completely* successful.  So if that is the end of the string, then - oh happy day!

```
  if (n > 0 && a[n] == '\0') {
    sscanf(a, "%d.%d.%d", day, mon, year);
    // check ranges if desired
    if (*day < 1 || *day > 31) return 0;
    if (*mon < 1 || *mon > 12) return 0;

    // additional checks
    TDB_Code();

    return 1; // success
  }
  return 0; // failure
}
```